# Create and call python function from string via C API

Tags: python, c, embed

Is it possible to load a python function from a string and then call that function with arguments and get the return value?

I'm using the python C API to run python code from inside my C++ application. I'm able to load a module from a file using `PyImport_Import`, get a function object from that using `PyObject_GetAttrString`, and call the function with `PyObject_CallObject`. What I'd like to do is to load the module/function from a string instead of a file. Is there some equivalent to `PyImport_Import` which would allow me to pass it a string instead of a file? I need to pass arguments to the function I'm calling and I need access to the return value, so I can't just use `PyRun_SimpleString`.

---

## **Edit:**

I found this solution after getting turned on to `PyRun_String`. I'm creating a new module, getting its dictionary object, passing that along in a call to `PyRun_String` to define a function in my new module, then getting a function object for that newly created function and calling it via `PyObject_CallObject`, passing my args. This is what I've found to solve my problem:
`main.cpp`

```
int main()
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pArgs, *pValue, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pGlobal = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *pLocal;

    //Create a new module object
    PyObject *pNewMod = PyModule_New("mymod");

    Py_Initialize();
    PyModule_AddStringConstant(pNewMod, "__file__", "");

    //Get the dictionary object from my module so I can pass this to PyRun_String
    pLocal = PyModule_GetDict(pNewMod);

    //Define my function in the newly created module
    pValue = PyRun_String("def blah(x):\n\tprint 5 * x\n\treturn 77\n", Py_file_input, pGlobal, pLocal);
    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    //Get a pointer to the function I just defined
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pNewMod, "blah");

    //Build a tuple to hold my arguments (just the number 4 in this case)
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    pValue = PyInt_FromLong(4);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

    //Call my function, passing it the number four
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    printf("Returned val: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pNewMod);
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Here is the rest of my original post, left for posterity:

Here's what I was doing originally:
`main.cpp`:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pArgs, *pValue, *pFunc;

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('')");
    pName = PyString_FromString("atest");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if(pModule == NULL)
    {
        printf("PMod is null\n");
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "doStuff");
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    pValue = PyInt_FromLong(4);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    printf("Returned val: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And `atest.py`:

```
def doStuff( x):
    print "X is %d\n" % x
    return 2 * x
```

Comment: It's not necessary to leave your post for posterity. Stack Overflow already has that covered. All edits to questions and answers are automatically archived, which we can see once our points reach a certain level. That helps us rollback bad edits, and trace the changes to better understand questions. So, instead of leaving it there, you can delete your changes and we can look at the edit log if need-be. Because of that, it's not even necessary to put in "Edit:".

Comment: For others who stumble over this: In the first code snippet, Py_Initialize is called too late. just that you know

Comment: Check if you use pValue two times the first reference must make memory leak

Comment: a question : the function defined in a single PyRun_String invocation, has to be entirely contained in a single invocation ? i.e. the body of the function cannot be split into successive invocations of PyRun_String ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PyRun_String` in the Python C API is probably what you're looking for. See: http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html

Comment: It's not clear how I would pass arguments to the function. It does look like I can define a function using `PyRun_String`, but I don't see how to call it with parameters that aren't just hard-coded string. That is, I could call PyRun_String again with "doStuff(7)" as the first argument, but that won't work if the argument is an object or something like that. Is there some way to call PyObject_GetAttrString to get the function object for doStuff if it's been defined via PyRun_String?

Comment: Accepting because it started me on the path to finding a solution, though I had to do a _lot_ of reading to get there. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't online for the last few hours, but it looks like you figured it out exactly. `PyRun_String` runs a block of Python code from a string and returns whatever the code would have returned -- I presume it's `None` in your case. After that, the function you've just evaluated is added to the local namespace -- you have to retrieve it from there using `PyObject_GetAttrString` and then call it. You might also want to check the return value of `PyRun_String` - if it is `NULL`, there was an exception while executing the code block.

Answer (score 7):

The answer contained in the question is excellent but I had some small troubles using it with [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/), so to save anyone else doing what I did, below is a slightly edited version that seems to work fine for this version of Python at least:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(void)
{
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue, *pFunc, *pModule, *pGlobal, *pLocal;

    Py_Initialize();

    pGlobal = PyDict_New();

    //Create a new module object
    pModule = PyModule_New("mymod");
    PyModule_AddStringConstant(pModule, "__file__", "");

    //Get the dictionary object from my module so I can pass this to PyRun_String
    pLocal = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    //Define my function in the newly created module
    pValue = PyRun_String("def blah(x):\n\ty = x * 5\n\treturn y\n",
        Py_file_input, pGlobal, pLocal);

    //pValue would be null if the Python syntax is wrong, for example
    if (pValue == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        return 1;
    }

    //pValue is the result of the executing code, 
    //chuck it away because we've only declared a function
    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    //Get a pointer to the function I just defined
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "blah");

    //Double check we have actually found it and it is callable
    if (!pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"blah\"\n");
        return 2;
    }

    //Build a tuple to hold my arguments (just the number 4 in this case)
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    pValue = PyLong_FromLong(4);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

    //Call my function, passing it the number four
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    fprintf(stdout, "Returned value: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));

    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Very useful for me. I used many parts of this code in my program.

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty old, however if anyone is still trying to figure this out (like I was) I'll provide my answer.

The original answer and updated answer by @kmp work for simple examples, however when something like an `import` statement is introduced into the code this doesn't work.

I found a working example here: https://awasu.com/weblog/embedding-python/writing-a-c-wrapper-library-part3/

In short (using Python 3.6 api):

- Read a python file in:

```py
std::string line, text;
std::ifstream in("the_file.py");
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
  text += line + "\n";
}
const char *data = text.c_str();
```

- Compile it to bytecode:

```py
PyObject *pCodeObj = Py_CompileString(data, "", Py_file_input);
```

- Create a module by executing the code:

```py
pModule = PyImport_ExecCodeModule("the_module", pCodeObj );
```

You can then continue by getting functions using `PyObject_GetAttrString` and calling them as in the examples above.