# Calling python method from C++ (or C) callback

Tags: c++, python, c, callback, python-c-api

I am trying to call methods in a python class from C++. The C++ method from which this is called is a C++ callback.

Within this method when I am trying to call python method, it was giving `segmentation fault`.

I have saved an instance of python function in a global variable like

```
// (pFunc is global variable of type PyObject*)
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "PlxMsgWrapper");
```

where `PlxMsgWrapper` is a python method, which will be used in the callback.

In the callback, the arguments are created as

```
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyString_FromString(header.c_str()),
                                 PyString_FromString(payload.c_str()));
```

When creating the

```
PyObject * pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, args);
```

In this line its giving segmentation fault. After this the actual python method is called as

```
PyObject* recv_msg_func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char *)"recvCallback");
args = PyTuple_Pack(1, pInstance);
PyObject_CallObject(recv_msg_func, args);
```

Comment: I have tried my best to elucidate properly. Please comment back if there are any issues.

Comment: Did you check that PyObject_GetAttrString actually returns something usable? Maybe the lookup failed for some reason. Perhaps 'module' was not initialized correctly?

Comment: @djf Actually, the control itself is not coming till that point. `PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, args)`. Its crashing while calling this method itself. In order to get rid of module problems, I am not loading that in the callback.

Comment: ah, I see. I misunderstood the question. Could you perhaps show a complete code example? If PyObject_CallObject segfaults, it's most likely because either pFunc or args haven't been initialized properly.

Comment: @djf `args` is initialized properly within the `callback` itself. Thats not a problem. `pFunc` is present globally. I suspected that and was initializing `pFunc` in the `callback` itself. But still the problem was coming.

Comment: @djf When initializing `pFunc` within the callback. The problem was coming while loading the `module` from `moduleString`. In this line `PyImport_Import(modString);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create and call python function from string via C API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789881/create-and-call-python-function-from-string-via-c-api)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do if you are invoking a Python function from a C/C++ callback. First when you save off your python function object, you need to increment the reference count with:

```
Py_INCREF(pFunc)
```

Otherwise Python has no idea you are holding onto an object reference, and it may garbage collect it, resulting in a segmentation fault when you try to use it from your callback.

Then next thing you need to be concerned about is what thread is running when your C/C++ callback is invoked. If you are getting called back from another non-Python created thread (i.e. a C/C++ thread receiving data on a socket), then you **MUST** acquire Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) before calling any Python API functions. Otherwise your program's behavior is undefined. To acquire the GIL you do:

```
void callback() {
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    // Get args, etc.

    // Call your Python function object
    PyObject * pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, args);

    // Do any other needed Python API operations

    // Release the thread. No Python API allowed beyond this point.
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
}
```

Also, in your extension module's init function, you should do the following to ensure that threading is properly initialized:

```
// Make sure the GIL has been created since we need to acquire it in our
// callback to safely call into the python application.
if (! PyEval_ThreadsInitialized()) {
    PyEval_InitThreads();
}
```

Otherwise, crashes and strange behavior may ensue when you attempt to acquire the GIL from a non-Python thread.

See [Non-Python Created Threads](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) for more detail on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) That was the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot - hadn't considered I might be in the wrong thread.

Answer (score 2):

Python should look for a module in the directory where it is being run 
from, however, if you think that the issue is that python is not finding 
your file, you can add an arbitrary directory on your computer to the 
module search path within your program:

```
// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();

// The following two lines to the trick:
// add path to your module to python's search paths
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"/path/to/python/module/here\")");

// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString("your_module");

// Load the module object
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "PlxMsgWrapper");

pArgs = ... 

if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) 
{
   PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
} else {
   PyErr_Print();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you can greatly simplify your code and avoid reference count issues with [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();

  object pyFunPlxMsgWrapper = import("your_module").attr("PlxMsgWrapper");
  pyFunPlxMsgWrapper(2, "string", "data");
  return 0;
}
```