# Segmentation fault when calling PyObject_CallObject using a global variable

Tags: c++, python

I have a C++ program receiving calls from users. Some of these calls should be processed by python scripts. This is how I am doing it:

- On start, it loads a Python interpreter using `Py_Initialize()` and loads some modules and functions. I keep references to them. This works.
- On each call, the corresponding function is called

The first time it works nice, but the second time I always get a segmentation fault when calling `PyObject_CallObject`. I have tried fixing this with the tips from [Calling python method from C++ (or C) callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606872/calling-python-method-from-c-or-c-callback/16609899#16609899), but it still doesn't work.

Moreover, if I try to run `PyRun_SimpleString("import <module_name>")`, I also get a segmentation fault! And this time I am not even using references.

Note: the initialization is done via a singleton pattern, so the first call happens immediately after the intitialization.

Comment: Can you strip down the program to a minimal, compilable example that still demonstrates the problem? This would make it easier for others to find the issue, and the process might even help you resolve it yourself.

Comment: I tried, but then it worked alright. I guess I am having problems with multi-threading... I am still trying to reproduce it

Comment: I can't answer my own question in the next six hours, so I explain it here briefly: a call to `PyList_SetItem` stole a reference to a variable I kept. Adding a `Py_INCREF` solved the problem. It had not to do with threads.

Comment: Good catch - a missing `Py_INCREF` can be painful and hard to debug as it results in corruption. If you feel the answer won't be of much use to future visitors, you also have the option of deleting the question.